# Android Koin DI can't get instance with named

Tags: android, dependency-injection, koin

Here is my code...

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
val myService: MyService by inject(named("MyService"))
val yourService: YourService by inject(named("YourService"))


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    myService.myServiceDo()
    yourService.yourServiceDo()
}
```

MyApp :

```
class MyApp : Application() {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    startKoin {
        androidContext(this@MyApp)

        module { myModule }
    }

}
```

IService Interface :

```
interface IService {
fun foo()}
```

MyService :

```
class MyService : IService {
override fun foo() {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}
fun myServiceDo(){
    Log.d("MyService", "myServiceDo...")
}
```

YourService :

```
class YourService : IService {
override fun foo() {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}

fun yourServiceDo() {
    Log.d("YourService", "yourServiceDo...")
}
```

myModule :

```
val myModule = module {
single<IService>(named("MyService")) { MyService() }

single<IService>(named("YourService")) { YourService() }
```

The error is like `org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class:'se.jun.koinex.IService' & qualifier:'MyService'. Check your definitions!`

I can't understand why it happens even if I did think I followed Koin Offical Documents.

Could you please help me? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oooops... there was a mistake in startKoin function.
For specify module, I should use modules function but there was a module...
And also,here

```
val myService: MyService by inject(named("MyService"))
val yourService: YourService by inject(named("YourService"))
```

the type of services should be IService.

If I wanna use MyService's or YourService's own functions, then should cast to applicable type.